# How to proper logout and navigate using Firebase and lazy loading

Tags: angular, firebase, routes, lazy-loading, logout

How in proper way logout and navigate user to the main view using Firebase AuthState?

I've got simple content layout which consist of header, router-outlet and footer. Header and footer content change depending on whether the user is logged in. In routing I'm using lazyloading (and import it in AppModule). To authorize users I'm using firebase. In AuthService constructor I subscribe to AuthStat.

Simplified content layout:

```
<app-heder [user]="user"></app-header>  
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer [user]="user"></app-footer>
```

Routing:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
       path: 'dashboard',
       loadChildren: './modules/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
    },
    {
       path: 'settings',
       loadChildren: './modules/app-settings/app-settings.module#AppSettingsModule'
    },
    {
       path: 'about',
       loadChildren: './modules/about/about.module#AboutModule'
    },
    {path: '**', redirectTo: '/dashboard'},
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {
            preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules,
            scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
            anchorScrolling: 'enabled'
        })
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Auth service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

    constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
                private router: Router) {
        this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((auth) => this._user = auth);
    }

    get currentUserObservable(): Observable<any> {
        return this.afAuth.authState;
    }

    public signOut(): void {
        this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
        this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
    }
}
```

Method used to get user in app.component (called in ngOnInit):

```
private getUser(): void {
    this.auth.currentUserObservable.subscribe(
        res => this.user = res,
        error => console.log(error)
      );
}
```

What works as it should:

1. User visit the website (route: 'dashboard')
2. User logged in
3. User logged out (still being on 'dashboard')

Everything works fine. 'user' variable have changed, the views in header and footer have changed.

What does not work as it should:

1. User visit the website (route: 'dashboard')
2. User logged in
3. User change the route for instance to 'settings'
4. User logged out (then automatically navigate to 'dashboard')

In fact, user logged out, navigation works, but the view in header and footer does not changed. 
This is due to the fact that the variable 'user' (in with I subscribe in) was not update. When I remove route navigation from signOut() method the variable 'user' change every time like it should.

It looks like the navigate 'blocks' in some way 'user' value change. Maybe it is related to my lazyloading structure?

I can't figure out where the problem is. Please give me some tips.